# Cross account codepipeline with S3 source in different account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-codepipeline, aws-event-bridge

I have 2 AWS account:

1. Account A: Codepipeline
2. Account B: S3 containing zip

The requirement is such that the codepipeline in account A will need S3 zip file as source stage from Account B.
Also the codepipeline should detect changes in the S3 path whenever there is a new zip file and invoke the pipeline.

Can anyone help me with the cross account roles and steps required in the above process please.

Comment: It would be best if you actually tried doing something, and then provide all details, including the roles and error messages, in your question.

Comment: @Marcin Not getting any lead to start with. I don't know how the Cloudwatch event trigger will invoke pipeline in different account.

Answer (score 0):

Create a pipeline in CodePipeline that uses resources from another AWS account -- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/pipelines-create-cross-account.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).